# storing live data in new cell in excel

Tags: excel, vba

i was trying to make macros for following task

cell A1 has live updating data which gets update on every 3 minutes.
Now task is copy data from A1 and store in new cell after every 3 minutes so we have lot of past data and can sketch chart of continuous data. The task starts with form control button and can be stopped by same.

thank you!!

I got this lines from internet-

```
Sub RunMe()
For Each cell In Range("B1:ZZ1")
    If cell.Value = vbNullString Then
        cell.Value = Range("A1")
        Exit Sub
    End If
Next cell

End Sub
```

AS A1 cell gets live data from web and macro stores this data (after every 3 min.) into new cell (starts from B1, after 3 min.stores into C1 ,after another 3 min.stores into c2)

i don't know how to add delay for 3 min. and where to add

Comment: The button starts a timer?  Could you post the code for that?  Also, where does this cell need to be copied to?  Cell A2, A3, etc?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an event macro to monitor cell **A1**.  Every time the cell gets refreshed, the event macro will store the new value.

We will use the **calculate event**.  In **A2** enter:

```
=A1
```

Each time **A1** changes, **A2** will be re-calculated.  Place the following code in the worksheet code area:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Calculate()
    Application.EnableEvents = False
        Call RunMe
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because it is worksheet code, it is very easy to install and automatic to use:

1. right-click the tab name near the bottom of the Excel window
2. select View Code - this brings up a VBE window
3. paste the stuff in and close the VBE window

If you have any concerns, first try it on a trial worksheet.

If you save the workbook, the macro will be saved with it.
If you are using a version of Excel later then 2003, you must save
the file as .xlsm rather than .xlsx

To remove the macro:

1. bring up the VBE windows as above
2. clear the code out
3. close the VBE window

To learn more about macros in general, see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/getstarted.htm

and

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee814735(v=office.14).aspx

To learn more about Event Macros (worksheet code), see:

http://www.mvps.org/dmcritchie/excel/event.htm

**Macros must be enabled for this to work!**

Comment: Thanks !! It works good, but task is to update next column only after 3 minutes.I tried to add delay but when macro executed excel hangs. I saw data was updating after 3 minutes but we cant do any other works on that excel.

Comment: @GAN I understand the issue....................I will update this answer later today........